# Insert dash in confidence interval instead of comma in R (gtsummary)

Tags: r, logistic-regression, confidence-interval, gtsummary

I am doing a logistic regression table with tbl_regression (gtsummary package). However, confidence intervals are displayed with a comma in between. Is there a way to put a dash instead?

[image]

So that it would be displayed **1.04 - 1.05** instead of 1.04, 1.05.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would consider creating a custom [theme](https://www.danieldsjoberg.com/gtsummary/articles/themes.html) with `gtsummary`. One of the theme elements is `ci.sep` which is the:

> string indicating separator between upper and lower bounds of
> confidence intervals

The default is a comma, and could be set to endash or other. Other journal themes may already consider this for confidence intervals.

Here is an example using `trial` data from the package.

```
library(gtsummary)

m1 <- glm(response ~ age + stage, trial, family = binomial)

my_theme <-
  list(
    "pkgwide-str:ci.sep" = " - "
  )

set_gtsummary_theme(my_theme)

tbl_regression(m1, exponentiate = TRUE)
```

**Output**

[image: table with dash for confidence interval instead of comma]